# NTFS with high CPU usage

Tags: performance, hard-drive, filesystem, data-transfer, xbian

I'm using a RPi B+ with XBian and transmission, and an external USB 2TB disk, which has an external power supply.

That disk is NTFS, and I've noticed that the CPU usage of the `mount-ntfs` process is really high..

What can I do to improve this situation, short of using ext4 that would impede the usage of that disk on other non-Linux systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a kernel driver; Xbian's `mount-ntfs` is presumably [a user space one](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsprogs), but the former is a different implementation. I would guess it will consume less resources when you are not actually doing anything with the partition.

However, it may not be available on Xbian.  Unmount the drive and try instead:

```
mount -i -t ntfs /path/to/partition /mount/point
```

This should avoid invoking the userspace driver because of `-i` ("-i, --internal-only: Don't call the [userspace] helper even if it exists <- `man mount`).  If you don't get any errors, check `ps -A | grep mount`.  *There should not be any such process running*; it will exit right away having invoked the kernel driver if present.

If there is such a process, it's probably the same thing as `mount-ntfs`.  If not, the partition should be mounted and available.

Comment: Done, there is still the mount.ntfs FUSE process running, so no result there :(

Comment: Don't know why, maybe thanks to a second reboot, now the root process kicked in :D I hope that helps, thanks!

Comment: New update: had to remove, NTFS-3G brought instability to transmission...

Comment: You also might want to add `-i` option to mount to ensure kernel space driver is used and not fuse. Although IIRC it has some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Add `-o big_writes` to your mount commmand or `big_writes` to `/etc/fstab`

So the mount command above would become:

`mount -i -t ntfs -o big_writes /path/to/partition /mount/point`